# why is react native video not working on android, but working on ios?

Tags: reactjs, video, native

installed react video v. 5.2.0

but an error in running android but running correctly in ios.

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react-native-video": "^5.2.0"
```

App.js
[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9q8L.jpg)

```html
import Video from 'react-native-video';

// create a component
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Video
        source={{Uri: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4'}}
        ref={ref => (this.player = ref)}
        style={{width: 300, height: 400}}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

pls, help Thanks.

Comment: You need to share the error also here. Note that video playback relies on the underlying nature platforms capabilities so it is possible the format is supported on Android but not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The `uri` parameter should be lowercase (as opposed to `Uri`).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).